# How to create custom serialization on different properties of an object

Tags: json.net

I have an object and I want to serialize it to a custom serialization format. e.g

```
     class MyObj
     {
        public string Name { get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string, string> KeyValues {get;set; }
     }
```

I want to camelcase Name but not KeyValues. Is this possible in Newtonsoft? I know how to do this for the entire object but not for specific properties.

So, the output should look like this:

```
    {
      "name" : "Mike", 
      "keyValues": 
       {
           "Abc": "x",
           "Prv": "y"
       }
    }
```

Comment: I used short example. 
but I have used camelcase

JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            
        };

this is for other objects in class. I need non camel case for only KeyValues inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to attribute the fields with JsonProperty and set the label that you want to use:

```
public class MyObj
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("KeyValues")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> KeyValues {get;set; }
}
```

JsonProperty is included in Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: this is not useful.
as I have used camelcase serializer for other properties, and I want to only customize several properties without camelcasing

Comment: Could you explain why is not useful, so I can help you? Using this attribute you can set any label you want, so I think you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I have used CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver 
as my class contains several nested classes which needs this. 
I want to control only few members not to have camel case